# Postman addon's like in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, postman

Is there a recommended add-ons in the firefox, which is has the most features that postman have?

Comment: Why don't you just use Chrome instead?

Comment: @benjaminz, Why chrome. Just because you are using it. Firefox is a capable browser, and the poster asked for Firefox plugins, so keep it relevant please.

Comment: @crafter I thought Postman was a Chrome-only app, is it not? That's why I suggested Chrome.

Comment: [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) reads: "software tools commonly used by programmers", so I believe it's not off-topic. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @Betlista Guidelines state questions should not be for opinions or recommendations. Too subjective and prone to flame wars.

Comment: You can now use Postman directly in your browser (FF, Chrome, Safari...): https://go.postman.co/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's a few:

- [Rested](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rested/?src=stackoverflow)
- [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)
- [REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/?src=userprofile)

Comment: They are not good at postman !!

Comment: He is right RESTClient and REST Easy are not as good as POSTMAN, my answer below gives a good alternative.
@Noitidart

Comment: I know this is an old post, but beware of RESTClient and its open bugs, like https://github.com/chao/RESTClient/issues/102

Comment: also Http Requester https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/

Comment: @melloc, the Environment function is really important, you need test in dev, in test, in UAT (Stage), in production. So same parameter in different environment has different value. This is why I say not good at postman.

Comment: Now Postman has native apps for windows, linux, and mac OS. So you don't have to rely on a browser, specifically chrome.

Answer (score 50):

I liked `PostMan`, it was the main reason why I kept using Chrome, now I'm good with `HttpRequester`

https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/?src=search

Comment: I'm a diehard Firefox user, so was reluctant to switch platforms just for Postman - thanks for the tip on HttpRequester!

Comment: @MandisaW, I am also =D Using the Nightly - e10s  build right now, the performance is great - Glad it helped :]

Comment: Excellent addon, i dont know why a firefox devuser doesnt create a postman alterative. Its pretty easy, the hard part is making the GUI pretty.

Comment: Definitely great REST tool, much better than REST Easy. Has requests history, pretty formatting for JSON and many other features

Comment: @rcBytes, it's not being maintained now? Last update was in Dec 2014

Comment: hey @Adarsh, I'm still using it with, never let me down = ]

Comment: @Jesse sure? I'm using it with no problem. The only problem I'm always facing is the handling of https connections, but the rest is great.

Comment: @jlanza Hm. I am using it with https, so maybe that's it. I'll remove my previous comment just in case. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Jesse the solution I found for the https issue is: 1) access the url using firefox, 2) accept the security exception, etc. 3) then use HTTPRequester. This way I manage to access my https REST interfaces.

Comment: Can HttpRequester capture requests directly from the browser, as Postman Interceptor does?

Comment: It seems to not be compatible with latest firefox. The author stated that he has no intention to develop it further. Instead he suggests: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rester/

Comment: HttpRequester add-on is no more compatible with the latest Firefox release. I am using v63.0.3

Comment: Where can I download the old version? Is it available?

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Comment: You can now use Postman directly in your browser (FF, Chrome, Safari...): https://go.postman.co/

Answer (score 7):

The feature that I'm missing a lot from postman in Firefox extensions is WebView
(preview when API returns HTML).

Now I'm settled with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (Inspectors > WebView)